# Keyboard command to change desktop

Tags: unity, compiz, shortcut-keys

I am currently running Ubuntu 13.04 on my laptop and I installed compiz-config in order to organize my workspace.

In compiz-config, choosing general options, the last tab is desktop size. Then there are three options, and the last one propose to change the number of desktops. I would like to have two differents desktops but I can't find how to switch between them.

Is there a shortcut to switch between these two (non-virtual) desktops?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set two workspaces, these shortcuts can be helpful to switch between them: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>.

In **CompizConfig Settings Manager** these shortcuts are set in **Deskop Wall** plugin, **Bindings** tab, and you can change them as you wish:

[image: switch between workspaces]

Comment: I already know those shortcuts, they allow to switch between two workspaces (or 6 workspaces what I use) but into the same desktop and they don't switch between the two desktops I configure into this tab desktop size, choosing number of desktops: 2. Maybe this parameter doesn't create a second desktop as I imagine.

Comment: @estelle.chslp From my point of view there is no difference between desktop and workspace.

Comment: So what this third line 'number of desktops' can add? The two first lines add virtual workspaces and what about this last one?

Comment: @estelle.chslp See [What is the Compiz option “Number of Desktops” for?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/40461/what-is-the-compiz-option-number-of-desktops-for)

Comment: Ok thanks, sorry, I should search better before asking.